# Built-in type efficiency

Tags: c++, performance, built-in

Under **The most efficient types** second [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Optimizing_C%2B%2B/Writing_efficient_code/Performance_improving_features#The_most_efficient_types)

> ...and when defining an object to store a floating point number, use the double type, ... The double type is two to three times less efficient than the float type...

Seems like it's contradicting itself?

And I read elsewhere (can't remember where) that computations involving ints are faster than shorts on many machines because they are converted to ints to perform the operations?  Is this true? Any links on this?

Comment: Don't micro-optimize your code until you have determined that it is needed. The differences here on a modern architecture are negligible.

Comment: In case it really matters to you – which it probably doesn't – you'll really have to benchmark these things on the actual hardware you are targeting.

Comment: You are also mis-quoting the reference: *“[…] when defining an object to store a floating point number, use the `double` type, except when the `long double` type is needed. If the resulting aggregate object is of medium or large size, replace […] the floating point types with the `float` type, except when greater precision is needed.”*

Comment: @clcto Where would they be getting "two to three times less efficient".  Sounds like a very strong statement.  Hopefully they were talking about space, which is obvious.

Comment: @anon if you were in a tight loop using SIMD instructions, it might be two times less efficient. That's rarely going to happen though. I agree with the first part of the statement "...use the double type", unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: @MarkRansom, it has certainly happened to me. For example in a matrix multiple kernel or in generating fractals: doubles are about half the speed of singles. If an operation is compute bandwidth bound and can use SIMD than single is twice as fast as double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can always argue about the quality of the contents on the site you link to. But the two quotes you refer to:

> ...and when defining an object to store a floating point number, use the double type, ...

and

> ... The double type is two to three times less efficient than the float type...

Refer to two different things, the first hints that using doubles will give much less problems due to the increased precision, while the other talks about performance. But honestly I wouldn't pay too much attention to that, chance is that if your code performs suboptimal it is due to incorrect choice of algorithm rather than wrong choice of primitive data type.

Here is a quote about performance comparison of single and double precision floats from one of my old teachers: Agner Fog, who has a lot of interesting reads over at his website: http://www.agner.org about software optimizations, if you are really interested in micro optimizations go take a look at it:

> *In most cases, double precision calculations take no more time than single precision. When the floating point registers are used, there is simply no difference in speed between single and double precision.* Long double precision takes only slightly more time. Single precision division, square root and mathematical functions are calculated faster than double precision when the XMM registers are used, while the speed of addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc. is still the same regardless of precision on most processors (when vector operations are not used).

*source:* http://agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf

While there might be different variations for different compilers, and different processors, the lesson one should learn from it, is that most likely you do not need to worry about optimizations at this level, look at choice of algorithm, even data container, not the primitive data type.

Comment: Yep. Choosing the wrong algorithm (that's easy!) easily drops performance from lightning-fast to won't complete before the heat-death of the universe. And that's with the right algorithm using grossly oversized types in comparison.

Comment: In my fractal code I process either four pixels at once using doubles with AVX or eight pixels at once using single floats. The single float method is about twice as fast.

Answer (score 4):

These optimizations are negligible unless you are writing software for space shuttle launches (which recently have not been doing too well). *Correct* code is far more important than *fast* code. If you require the precision, using doubles will barely affect the run time.

Things that affect execution time way more than type definitions:

1. **Complexity** - The more work there is to do, the more slowly the code will run. Reduce the amount of work needed, or break it up into smaller, faster tasks.
2. **Repetition** - Repetition can often be avoided and will inevitably ruin code performance. It comes in many guises-- for example, failing to cache the results of expensive calculations or of remote procedure calls. Every time you recompute, you waste efficiency. They also extend the executable size.
3. **Bad Design** - Self explanatory. Think before you code!
4. **I/O** - A program whose execution is blocked waiting for input or output (to and from the user, the disk, or a network connection) is bound to perform badly.

There are many more reasons, but these are the biggest. Personally, bad design is where I've seen most of it happen. State machines that could have been stateless, dynamic allocation where static would have been fine, etc. are the real problems.

Comment: More than that, it's not really fair to say that doubles are *always* slower. In some cases, they will be, particularly because they take more memory, and reading/writing twice as much data will generally always take twice as much time. But for raw calculations it may not even change the runtime more than a few percent.

Comment: @UpAndAdam Correct, Fast, Cheap. Pick two.

Comment: Whilst I fully agree, it doesn't really answer the ACTUAL question.

Comment: There are cases where double is faster. For example with horizontal SIMD operations such as the `hadd` instruction.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the hardware, the actual CPU (or FPU if you like) performance of `double` is somewhere between half the speed and same speed on modern CPU's [for example add or subtract is probably same speed, multiply or divide may be different for larger type], when compared to `float`.

On top of that, there are "fewer per cache-line", so if when there is a large number of them, it gets slower still because memory speed is slower. Per cache-line, there are half as many `double` values -> about half the performance if the application is fully memory bound. It will be much less of a factor in a CPU-bound application.

Similarly, if you use SSE or similar SIMD technologies, the `double` will take up twice as much space, so the number of actual calculation with be half as many "per instruction", and typically, the CPU will allow the same number of instructions per cycle for both `float` and `double` - except for some operations that take longer for `double`. Again, leading to about half the performance.

So, yes, I think the page in the link is confusing and mixing up the ideal performance setup between `double` and `float`. That is, from a pure performance perspective. It is often much easier to get noticeable calculation errors when using `float` - which can be a pain to track down - so starting with `double` and switching to `float` if it's deemed necessary because you have identified it as a performance issue (either from experience or measurements).

And yes, there are several architectures where only one size integer exists - or only two sizes, such as 8-bit `char` and 32-bit `int`, and 16-bit `short` would be simulated by performing the 32-bit math, and then dropping the top part of the value. For example [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_instruction_set#Integer) has only got 32-bit operations, but can store and load 16-bit values to memory. It doesn't necessarily make it slower, but it certainly means that it's "not faster".

Comment: Yes, exactly, packing four doubles instead of eight floats will be half as fast in some cases. I certainly see that. Also, there are a few cases where double is faster than single. The horizontal add and dot product instructions are faster for double than for float. That's not surprising because the the horizontal instructions are implemented in sequence so the single ones have to perform twice as many operations as the double ones.